# Substituting with \StrSubstitute does not work

Tags: substitution

I am having a problem substituting string using `\StrSubstitute`. The way I understand the function, [as according to the documentation (page 7/8)](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf), it should work with three arguments. It should search the text for the first argument, and the replace the second argument within this first argument with the third argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\StrSubstitute{abcde}{d}{D}

blablabla
abcde

\input{mwe2}

cdeba

\end{document}
```

and the input file `mwe2.tex` is just

```
abcde

abcde

12345
```

However, the result of this in the PDF file is just:

abcDe

blablabla

abcde

abcde

abcde

12345

cdeba

i.e. the software places the string `abcde` at the location of the command `\StrSubstitute`, and then replaces `d` with `D` here, but ignoring the string `abcde` anywhere else in the document.

Can anyone help?
Best,
Marie

Comment: `StrSubstitute` does not work on all upcoming strings, only on the argument `abcde`, regardless what's inside `mwe2.tex`

Comment: but if it works only on the argument, and not on further occurences of the argument elsewhere in the text, then what will be the use of this function? Then I will manually have to work through the whole file and place `StrSubstitute` everywhere where I have an `abcde`, but then I can just replace `abcde` directly, if that's what you're saying.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's what `Search And Replace` for in a editor. Perhaps it works with the `l3reg` package

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not find anything on the web regarding an `l3reg` latex package.
I'm aware of the use of `search and replace` in a document, but this does not work on `input` files that are generated by another software. And if it only works in the text, then my point is: what is the point in programming the `\StrSubstitute` command at all if `\StrSubstitute{abcde}{d}{D}` needs to replace `abcde` everyhwere, and hence does nothing more than any editor's function `replace all abcde with abcDe`? Then this command would have no right to exist at all, so I'm sure there must be something to it?

Comment: I meant `l3regex`, sorry. You're misunderstanding `StrSubstitute`. If the `abcde` is hidden in a macro, say, `\foo`, then StrSubstitute is useful!. `\foo` can be anything (well, to some extent only, of course)

Answer (score 3):

`\StrSubstitute` does only act on the first argument content, i.e. it is a one - time - replacement. Following occurences of the source string are disregarded unless they are in the 1st argument. The usability of `\StrSubstitute` is improved if the source string is contained in a macro, say, `\newcommand{\foo}{abcde}`.

However, `\StrSubstitute{\input{mwe2}{...}{...}` would not work, due to expansion issues.

I tried to use the `l3regex` package (for the very first time) and it's quite easy for simple regular expressions (`abcde` is simple ;-)

The `\SearchAndReplace` macro opens the file `mwe2.tex` and replaces the occurences of `abcde` with `abcDe` (however, I don't think it works if there's a line break between `abc and`de` for example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l_marie_input_stream 
\NewDocumentCommand{\SearchAndReplace}{mmm}{%
  \ior_open:Nn \l_marie_input_stream {#1}% Open the file
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_marie_input_stream {% Read line by line
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {##1}% Store the line 
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {#2} {#3} \l_tmpa_tl % Replace #2 by #3
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl % Display the (modified) line content
  }
  \ior_close:N \l_marie_input_stream % close the file
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

With \verb!\StrSubstitute!

\StrSubstitute{abcde}{d}{D}

blablabla
abcde

Now with \verb!\SearchAndReplace!

\SearchAndReplace{mew2.tex}{abcde}{abcDe}

cdeba

\end{document}
```

Here is `mew2.tex`

```
abcde abcde

abcde

12345
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Would you consider `\tl_set_from_file:Nnn`?

Comment: @egreg: Ah, again some addition to `l3file` which is hidden in the backyard of the manual ;-). I'll try to change later on

Comment: this is great, but what if I need to do several replacements in the input file, such as replacing `abcde` with `abcDe` and `xyz` with `xYZ`?

Comment: @Marie.P. You're changing the question!

Comment: yes, I am afraid that your solution might not work anymore. I'm sorry, when providing a _minimum_ working example, I did not think of the specific case that there could be a solution that helps in the MWE, but not in my case with several strings.
You provided a solution that works if I only want to substitute one string, but the general case where someone would like to change several strings is just one step away.
But does anyone perhaps have any more ideas?