# In a table, give an empty line the height 0, so that it virtually disappears

Tags: tables, expl3

I am using an add-on to Stata in order to generate Latex-Tables that show estimation results and significance levels for some models.

On of these programs creates table of the following form, which I then input in another document using the `expl3` package. I present an adapted MWE of this file, which I call mwe2.tex:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\hline
line 1  &   a  &  b  \\ \hline
main    &      &     \\ \hline
x       &   y  &  z  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

For some reason, there is a row included that contains only the term "main" and is empty otherwise. *This needs to be deleted.*
Now comes the actual file that I *can* edit and work with (whereas the above code is given). I input the above code via the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l_marie_input_stream 
\NewDocumentCommand{\SearchAndReplace}{mmm}{%
  \ior_open:Nn \l_marie_input_stream {#1}% Open the file
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_marie_input_stream {% Read line by line
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {##1}% Store the line 
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {#2} {#3} \l_tmpa_tl % Replace #2 by #3
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl % Display the (modified) line content
  }
  \ior_close:N \l_marie_input_stream % close the file
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
abc\\

\SearchAndReplace{mwe2}{main}{maaaain}

def
\end{document}
```

[image: ![The problem]

Following the solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287223/substituting-with-strsubstitute-does-not-work), I input the file while replacing the term `main` with something else, but not with `%main`, because then the compilation gives an error.

I tried to replace the complete line with an empty space, i.e.

```
\SearchAndReplace{mwe2}{main&  &   \\}{ }
```

But this does not work--nothing changes. I precisely copied the content of the whole above line into the "replace-box" in the other document, but to no avail.

My second idea is to replace simply the work `main` with , which works fine, but leaves me with an empty line in the document:

```
\SearchAndReplace{mwe2}{main}{ }
```

[image]

My plan is now to replace `main` with some other code that allows me to set the height of the row in the table to 0. In this way, I would have a work-around that virtually removes the unnecessary line, by removing the content and setting its height to zero. However, I did some research, yet cannot find a command in latex that can be used to define the height of a single, *specific* row to be zero.

Comment: Why don't you just skip the line if it contains "main" in expl3 (sure there is a way to do it...). I tried to substitute with `\relax` to avoid the `\par` given by the white line, but to no avail, and I am not versed in `expl3` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Being not versed in `expl3`, I would rater use a shell escape in this case. You have to adapt this to your operating system, but on Unix-like is quite simple; let this file being `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
abc

\input{|"grep -v ^main mwe2.tex"}

def
\end{document}
```

...and then run it with `pdflatex --shell-escape main-tex`

The command

```
grep -v ^main file
```

outputs all the lines in `file` that *do not* (`-v`) start (`^`) with the word "main", and the result is input into LaTeX which will never see the line starting with "main".

Result:

[image: Result with shell escape]

#### NOTICE The following old answer here is for the first version of the question, that was completely different....

Hmmm... putting an `%` (comment) before "main" works here. (for little value of "work" --- you should *really* edit your code snippet so that it is compilable, with all the packages and option you load which probably do the difference).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{collage}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{big}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{small}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{together}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{separated}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{nophoto}\\
\hline
%main        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
\(N\)       &         798         &         791         &         803         &         803         &         798         &         435         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I actually did not think of that, but I tried it and it did not work. Following your suggestion, I have now adapted my code and given an MWE to show the problem. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Ups, now it's a completely different problem... I suggest you to add `expl3` tag and explicitly say it in the text.