# Using \StrSubstitute in a macro definition

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, xstring

I would like to create a macro that typesets the argument using `\emph` and also creates a label with that name. My names contain underscores so I tried to use `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\tactic}[1]{
\label{\StrSubstitute{#1}{\_}{}}
\emph{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\tactic{EXISTS_TAC}

\end{document}
```

but I get

```
! Use of \@xs@StrSubstitute@@ doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
\def \reserved@b {#3}\futu... l.12 
\tactic{EXISTS_TAC}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: xstring commands are not expandable so can not be used in contexts like this, also `_` are allowed in `\label` so you could simply do nothing here.

Comment: note perhaps the answer to my question, which uses `\SearchAndReplace` instead of `\StrSubstitute`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287223/substituting-with-strsubstitute-does-not-work

Comment: On the other hand, `\emph{EXISTS_TAC}` will end up with an error. You probably want to input `\tactic{EXISTS\_TAC}` and remove `\_` from the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have the reverse problem: an input such as `\emph{EXISTS_TAC}` will raise an error, whereas `\label{EXISTS_TAC}` is completely safe.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\tactic}[1]{%
  \emph{\noexpandarg\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\_}}\label{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tactic{EXISTS_TAC}

It was on page~\pageref{EXISTS_TAC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastringN' macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function tactic ( s ) 
   tex.sprint ( "\\label{"..s.."}" )
   tex.sprint ( "\\emph{\\detokenize{"..s.."}}" )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\tactic[1]{\directlua{tactic(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\tactic{EXISTS_TAC} \quad \tactic{_^&@$<>}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove underscores from names of referencing-labels but if you insist:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\tactic}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\textunderscore=\relax
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}[\mytemp]%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\emph
  \expandafter{\mytemp}%
  \begingroup
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{}[\mytemp]%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\label
  \expandafter{\mytemp}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tactic{EXISTS_TAC}  \pageref{EXISTSTAC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that in case of using the **hyperref**-package `\label` doesn't place an anchor for hyperlinks and that your `\tactic`-command in any case doesn't change any counter via `\refstepcounter` so that referencing the label via `\ref` or `\nameref` or `\autoref` will lead to referencing the superordinate item of sectioning. `\pageref` will deliver the page-number of the page where the output of the corresponding `\tactic`-command occurs.